# Read hid mouse/keyboard on windows (hidapi)

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, hidapi

I have an application on Linux which use hidapi to read data of a complex device (create by Qt5.3). This device has several interface HID whose one type "mouse" and one type "keyboard". 
On Linux I have no problem to get all data.
I need to deploy my app also on Windows. I can display all several device and interface but I can't open connection with interface type "mouse" or "keyboard". (hid_open_path return null).
I have seen Windows don't permit to open connection with mouse and keyboard (because this device are already use by Windows). 
How can I get around this prohibition ? How I can I prevent Windows to open a handle with specfic keyboard or mouse ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Windows as a security measure does not allow opening a mouse or keyboard type device with GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, as a safeguard against keyloggers etc.

https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/issues/247#issuecomment-161152387

If anyone figured out a workaround, please post a comment to this answer.